# Why doesn't "Save session for future logins" save open terminals?

Tags: xubuntu, login

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 with Xubuntu Desktop. Upon shutdown, the GUI provides the option "Save session for future logins", a feature I like a lot. However it fails to restore any programs I started from a terminal, while it works perfectly for those I started by, say, clicking on an icon in the task bar. Why is that? How should I start those programs I currently start from the terminal with an alias in order to restore them with the "Save session" feature?